# ie8 animate jquery issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

It really makes me crazy.

I made a navigation fadeout menu by scrolling and hover.
But It show transparent background png files and texts are distorted in IE8 and lower versions.

I can't find good solution. :(
Please help me!!!

This is my script code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web/upload/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js">

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop != 0)
            $('#header').stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},300);
        else    
                $('#header').stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},300);
    });

    $('#header').hover(
        function (e) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if(scrollTop != 0){
                $('#header').stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},300);
            }
        },
        function (e) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if(scrollTop != 0){
                $('#header').stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},300);
            }
        }
    );
});

</script>
```

Comment: please create a fiddle or a reference link to see in ie8

Comment: Just a tip, IE8 is absolutely terrible when it comes to fading in / out images via jQuery.

Comment: @TheMechanic JSFiddle is not good in IE8

Comment: IE is actually pretty crap with PNG files, often showing the alpha layer as solid black.  Google for transparency and opacity issues with IE to find out more.

Comment: Also, you don't need to animate opacity to 0 and 1.  Just use `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` instead :)

Comment: what you say about hacks for ie in usage of png's images

Comment: Transparent png in combination with _opacity_ which is done via non standart filters for IE 8 and lower behave bad. Sometimes you can solve it with clever restructuring of your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about just posting a comment, but I feel this warrants an "answer".

Looking at your code I can see you're executing code like $(window) and $('#header') for every scroll movement.  That's quite expensive and may affect how IE8 perform.  Plus, this code

```
$('#header').stop().animate({'opacity': '0'}, 300);
```

is going to execute over and over when the user is scrolling from the top, which probably won't be a smooth effect.  I would start by recoding your scroll function then go from there.  Try something like this (untested..sorry):

```
(function(window) {
    // Store your objects in vars outside of the scroll function
    var $header = $('#header'),            
        $window = $(window),
        headerVisible = true,
        fadeHeight = parseInt($header.outerHeight() / 2);

    $window.scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > fadeHeight && headerVisible) {
            headerVisible = false;
            $header.stop().animate({'opacity': '0'}, 300);
        } else if (scrollTop < fadeHeight && !headerVisible) {
            headerVisible = true;
            $header.stop().animate({'opacity': '1'}, 300);
        }
    });

    // Add your hover code here...and reuse the variables for $window and $header

// Pass in the 'global' window so we get faster access to a local-scope version
})(window);
```